# How to include an obligatory argument in the definition of a default optional argument?

Tags: macros, optional-arguments, arguments

I want to implement something with the same structure as the next command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xargs}

\providecommandx*{\countryinfo}[4][{3=undefined},{4=In #2 people like drinking #1.}]{%
\noindent
    1:  #1\\
    2:  #2\\
    3:  #3\\
    4:  #4\\
} 

\begin{document}

\countryinfo{beer}{Germany}

\countryinfo{tequila}{Mexico}[Mexico City]

\countryinfo{vodka}{Russia}[Moskow][Russia is the biggest country in the world.]

\end{document}
```

But it gives an error due to the default optional fourth argument's definition.

If I remove the #2 and #1 from the default optional argument's definition everything works just fine.

But I want to know, how can I make this happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's very easy with `xparse`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\countryinfo}{
  m % mandatory
  m % mandatory
  O{undefined} % optional, default 'undefined'
  O{In #2 people like drinking #1.} % optional, default as defined
}{%
\noindent
    1:  #1\\
    2:  #2\\
    3:  #3\\
    4:  #4
}

\begin{document}

\countryinfo{beer}{Germany}

\countryinfo{tequila}{Mexico}[Mexico City]

\countryinfo{vodka}{Russia}[Moskow][Russia is the biggest country in the world.]

\end{document}
```

[image]